RAW, how does Full Power Leaps work when you crash into something before the movement ends?
Relevant Full Power Flaw text for reference (pg. 167 PHB):

You can only leap your maximum distance; you can make shorter leaps only by not using your Leaping effect at all, just the normal jumping distance for your Strength.

Essentially I was looking into Charge Attacks, Slam Attacks, Crashing via Knockback, Fall Damage, and others and found no real RAW answer for what happens here. By points its just a Flat -1, but rather than the Flaw itself I'm more interested in the extra utility Full Force Leaps may include when you use Leaping as horizontal movement (since there's no specific direction for jumping) and simply crashing into people in a way similar to how you can have Movable Created Objects deal damage through them falling without using your action by dropping them for a similar kind of damage without action tech.
Is there some mention about this in other books? Otherwise you can kinda just jump at walls after being rocketed towards them and suffer no consequences for hurdling into them.

You are correct that there is no real RAW ruling for this. Rather, it's the job of the GM to adjudicate it. If you, as the GM, decide there's no consequence, then there's no consequence. If you, as a GM, decide to allow for a Dodge check to avoid obstacles, that's something you can do. If you want to treat it like Falling damage by allowing an Acrobatics check to reduce damage from something that you logically can't dodge, then that's something you can do.
If you're purposefully crashing into people, indeed, that sounds like a textbook case of a Slam attack with an attack roll, possibly damage to yourself, and all of that. Going by strict d20 rules (which, admittedly, M&M typically departs from a bit although I'm not aware of a specific rule here other than Rule 0), you'd be stopped by the first person because, in the d20 system, there is no penetration unless specifically noted. A sheet of paper protects you from a crossbow bolt just as easily as a stone wall because it only hits one target. In actuality, most GMs will make an on-the-spot ruling as to how an attack might penetrate a target (for example, having you continue to move with an incapacitated target). 2E had some additional rules for crashing through obstacles for knockback that might be applicable, but they chose not to make that explicit for 3E (as you probably saw on the podcast, Steve is big on the idea of GMs deciding how to run their own games).
